# HTTPS websites slow on Phone

Tags: networking, wi-fi, https

I am trying to investigate why our Phones are experiencing slow browsing to HTTPS sites.

It happens only the first time after the phone in question has been locked for a couple of minutes or more.
So when browsing to a https site after unlocking it, it takes over 1 minute.
Then, suddenly everything works until the next time we lock the phone screen and leave it for a while.

We are on my company wifi, and it is only happening there it seems.

I have tried everything when it comes to the router, and it is not an ISP fault.

Tried to use packetcapture app while connecting to a https site after unlocking phone, seems to be port 443 used by the https websites.

If I open for example BBC.COM (which seems to use a non secure port 80) it works fast and normal.

Any ideas?

BTW:
Traceroute and Pinging shows great results to the https sites, and download speeds are great as well.
Happens only on browsers (Both chrome and Stock samsung browsers).

Thx

Comment: Questions about Samsung Android phones are out of scope here at Superuser

Comment: @Ramhound It is not regarding a samsung in particular, it is regarding HTTPS. Any phone will do.

Comment: Do you have an IDPS or traffic scanning system that scans encrypted traffic? this might be done to combat remote command and data ex-filtration by malware, rogue employees,  etc. many such systems Man-in-the-middle the HTTPS negotiation process to replace the cryptographic attributes with the scanners, making the traffic visible. Most such devices will block a connection until it has time to re-negotiate the encrypted session,  so if the device is lacking capacity to meet demand, that would slow HTTPS traffic exclusively, and affect all users on the wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your device. If you have already updated your device, you may have downloaded a bad update. Unfortunately, this happened to me too. After i downloaded my update, my phone kept on freezing on the facebook market place. Sprint suggested that i just bring my device to the store. Hope this was helpful.